# iOS8 - Button does not react after starting NSTimer

Tags: ios, xcode, button, ios8, nstimer

i have problem with my simple iOS Timer app. On iOS 7 it works without problems but on iOS 8 systems my start button does not react anymore after initializing the NSTimer.

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)StartStop:(id)sender {
    if (startbutton == NO){
        [StartButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        startbutton= YES;

        rundenzaehler = 0;
        RundenText = @"";
        [self Start];
        startDate = [[NSDate date] init];

    }else {
      [StartButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        startbutton= NO;
        [stopwatchTimer invalidate];
        stopwatchTimer = nil;
        startDate = nil;
    }
}

- (void)Start{
    [RundenTextView setText:@""];
    stopwatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.001 target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [stopwatchTimer fire];
}

- (void)tick:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    //NSTimeInterval interval = -[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    NSTimeInterval interval =[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

    int millis = ((int)interval)% 1000;
    int seconds = (((int)interval)/1000) %60;
    int minutes = (((int) (interval/1000) - seconds) / 60) % 60;
    int hours = (((int) interval/1000) - seconds - 60 * minutes) % 3600;


    ZeitString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d:%.3d", hours,
                                 minutes, seconds, millis];

    [elapsedTime setText:ZeitString];
}
```

I have no idea why it works without problems on iOS 7 and not on iOS 8. Perhaps someone can help me out. Is it possible that iOS 8 has a problem with a running NSTimer which is changing a value of a text view every 0.001 seconds?

I tried it with other NSTime intervals and with 0.1 it works without problems. But already with 0.01 the button does not react anymore. Is there another way to show elapsed time on milliseconds?

Comment: what're you expecting here?

Comment: an answer why it works on iOS 7 and why the button freezes on iOS 8 - and perhaps a solution how it could work would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `- (IBAction)StartStop:(id)sender function.` You have called it like your button's name. So it's consider a get, not properly a function, or something like that.

Change the name like in "StartStopButtonPressed" so you will not have more problem.

Comment: I changed the name but still the same problem. My Button had the name StartButton. So it had a different name before...Had me greatly wondered if the problem had been at the method name.